# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, image, typescript

I have a problem with loading images in Angular 4, I found how to solve it by creating a variable in the ts file and using [src]="variablename". However, I have now another problem, I want to set the variable using a concatenation but with the code that I have I got:

```
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined"
```

The piece of code I want to use is:

```
flag:any = require("../../../assets/images/flags/"+this.selectedLanguage.flag+".png");
```

How can I successfully use this so it can be declared?, for example, as:

```
flag:any = require("../../../assets/images/flags/ge.png");
```

The whole code I have is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FuseConfigService } from '../../core/services/config.service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { lang } from 'moment';

@Component({
    selector   : 'fuse-toolbar',
    templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})

export class FuseToolbarComponent
{
    userStatusOptions: any[];
    languages: any;
    selectedLanguage: any;
    showLoadingBar: boolean;
    horizontalNav: boolean;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private fuseConfig: FuseConfigService,
        private translate: TranslateService
    )

    {
        this.userStatusOptions = [
            {
                'title': 'Online',
                'icon' : 'icon-checkbox-marked-circle',
                'color': '#4CAF50'
            },
            {
                'title': 'Away',
                'icon' : 'icon-clock',
                'color': '#FFC107'
            },
            {
                'title': 'Do not Disturb',
                'icon' : 'icon-minus-circle',
                'color': '#F44336'
            },
            {
                'title': 'Invisible',
                'icon' : 'icon-checkbox-blank-circle-outline',
                'color': '#BDBDBD'
            },
            {
                'title': 'Offline',
                'icon' : 'icon-checkbox-blank-circle-outline',
                'color': '#616161'
            }
        ];

        this.languages = [
            {
                'id': 'uk',
                'title': 'English',
                'flag': 'uk'
            },
            {
                'id': 'ge',
                'title': 'German',
                'flag': 'ge'

            },
            {
                'id': 'es',
                'title': 'Spanish',
                'flag': 'es'
            },
            {
                'id': 'fr',
                'title': 'French',
                'flag': 'fr'
            }
        ];

        this.selectedLanguage = this.languages[0];
        console.log(this.selectedLanguage.flag);



        router.events.subscribe(
            (event) => {
                if ( event instanceof NavigationStart )
                {
                    this.showLoadingBar = true;
                }
                if ( event instanceof NavigationEnd )
                {
                    this.showLoadingBar = false;
                }
            });

        this.fuseConfig.onSettingsChanged.subscribe((settings) => {
            this.horizontalNav = settings.layout.navigation === 'top';
        });

    }

    search(value)
    {
        // Do your search here...
        console.log(value);
    }

    setLanguage(lang)
    {
        // Set the selected language for toolbar
        this.selectedLanguage = lang;

        // Use the selected language for translations
        this.translate.use(lang.id);

    }

    logo:any = require("../../../assets/images/logos/logo.png");
    avatarGuest:any = require("../../../assets/images/avatars/profile.jpg");
    flag:any = require("../../../assets/images/flags/"+this.selectedLanguage.flag+".png");


}
```

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a TypeScript related error. Do stop using `any` though. it's buying you absolutely nothing since that's the type of a VAR require anyway anyway - just leave it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the properties `logo`, `avatarGuest` and `flag` are initialised before the body of the constructor is called, so by the time you are getting the path for the flag `this.selectedLanguage` is indeed `undefined`. You can simply move this line into the body of the constructor after you initialise `this.selectedLanguage`:

```
// ... your code
this.selectedLanguage = this.languages[0];     
console.log(this.selectedLanguage.flag);

flag:any = require("../../../assets/images/flags/"+this.selectedLanguage.flag+".png");
```

Comment: Thank you! This sort of worked. The only thing is that the final code was:  `this.flag = require("../../../assets/images/flags/"+this.selectedLanguage.flag+".png");` And `flag:any;` declared at the beginning of the class.

Comment: Glad it helped!